# Paddle collision side detection using Graphics

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, graphics, collision-detection

I've implemented a kind of Pong where the paddles (*Rectangle2D*) can rotate.
To obtain more accuracy, many things are managed by *Graphics2D*.
The rotation too is managed by the methods *rotate(...)* of the previous told class.

To reach a realistic bounce, I need to know where the ball hits the paddle (only the side, not the particular point).

I've tried to define (and rotate) two *Rectangle2D* that represent the back and the front side of the paddle and then recognize the bounce in one of these two by the method *hit(Rectangle2D r, Shape s, boolean onStroke)*, but it doesn't work properly.

Here is the java class *Graphics2D*:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have one rectangle for your paddle and know the center of rectangle and circle and the rotation of your rectangle.
Assuming a rotation of zero means, your rectangle is aligned horizontally (width > height).

- Calculate the difference vector (center of circle) - (center of rectangle)
- Get the angle of that vector and subtract the rotation of your rectangle (angle of vector is Math.atan2(y, x))
- The resulting value a tells you the relative direction of your circle
- Make sure a lies between 0 and 2*pi

q = Math.atan2(height of rectangle, width of rectangle)

- If a is between q and pi-q, your circle has hit on the front long (upper) side.
- If a is lower than q or bigger than 2*pi-q it's on the right side.
- If a is between pi-q and pi+q it's on the left side.
- If a is between pi+q and 2pi-q it's hit the bottom of your rectangle

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used a reworked version of it. Below I am going to post my code.